# a value of type cannot be assigned to an entity of type\

Tags: types, malloc, new-operator

```
void School::plusWorker()
{
    int i;
    Worker** temp;
    temp = new Worker* [numPworking+1];
    if (workers != 0)
    {
        cout << "Error in workers malloc step 1" << endl;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < numPworking; ++i)
    {
        temp[i] = workers[i];
        delete workers[i];
    }
    delete []workers;
    ++numPworking;
    workers = temp;
}
```

I don't understand the Error I have two objects of pointers to classes one in the name "**workers" and the other one in the name "**temp".
I want to add one place in my worker's-arr so I  copy all the data from **workers to **temp then I point from there back to workers.
but he does not allow it, some help, please?